# Garage door opener has loud buzz while operating

Tags: garage-door-opener

About a week ago, my garage door opener (Genie Screwdrive Pro) started making a very loud buzz sound while the door moves.

All the google searches for buzz or hum from an opener either point to a constant hum all the time (transformer) or a loud buzz and no movement on the door (start capacitor).

However, mine still operates just fine, and the buzz only happens when the motor is running.

The motor unit is securely fastened to the garage ceiling, it's not loose or rattling that I can tell by shaking it with my hands (both parallel to the center rail and perpendicular).

Is my start capacitor about to die on me? Would that be a symptom?

Comment: It could also be a relay that is getting weak and buzzing when start caps go they usually have trouble opening before they go all the way.

Comment: This buzzing is so loud it dominates the usual motor sounds and the sounds of the door rollers rattling in the tracks. Would a relay chattering be that loud?

Comment: Yes they can be extremely loud on larger models I use if they get dirty sometimes they can be heard 50' out side the room they are in. (Of course this is in a lumber mill and a small piece of saw dust can cause them to do this).